# Why isn't the media queries working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to make a responsive portfolio using only HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.
The navigation bar code, I got from w3 schools and made a few changes.
Anything after the navigation bar isn't being responsive. I tried using flex-box and media queries but the media queries option doesn't seem to work. How do I make this responsive?

```css
.navbar{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: white;
  
  font-family: lobster;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-brand{
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.fa{
 color: #337aa9;
}

.page-one{
 background: url("https://s20.postimg.org/otq1xf6h9/Optimized_abcd.jpg");
 font-family: lobster;
 color: #337aa9;
 height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: none;
    opacity: 0.1;
   
    }

 .cont1{
   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 3%
    padding-bottom:3%;
    opacity:1;
    
    color:white;
 }

.flex-item {
    background-color:none;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:1;
}

.dp{
 height:240px;
 border-radius:50%;
}

.cont2{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
 .body{
  font-size:3px;
  font-family:arial;
 .dp{
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c7082764ea.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c7082764ea.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<Head>
<title>Puneeth</title>
</Head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Puneeth S</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Contact me<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <div class="page-one">
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container cont1">
  <div class="flex-item text-center">
    <h1>Puneeth S</h1>
    <h3>Engineer by chance, Developer by choice</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="row cont2">
   <div class="img-responsive">
 <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/uguojmpvx/abcd.jpg" class="dp">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a class of `.body` or are you trying to target the `body` element? You're also missing a closing curly bracket to your `.body` declaration.

Comment: sorry about that. was trying to target the body element. I did correct it now and removed the "." but the problem isn't going.

Comment: Did you also add the missing closing curly bracket? (i.e., `body { ... }`)

Comment: Yep. I did add the curly bracket.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting, only other thing I can suggest is use the browser dev tools to see if there is possibly another style from your other style sheets that's overwriting your definitions.

Comment: I did check. I don't think that's the issue.
This happened with another html document of mine as well.

Comment: Do you have this page somewhere live where I can inspect it?

Comment: Nope. I can mail the files to you though if that's okay.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu It worked after I changed the width of the flex-container to 100% but I still don't know why the parameters of the other tags didn't vary though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The media query worked after I changed the width of the flex-container to 100 %.